# Change input name incrementally upon appending in jquery

Tags: jquery

Have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var counter = 1;
        var maxAppend = 0;

        $("#addItem").click(function() {
            if (maxAppend >= 10) return;
                var task = $('#searchresults').val();
                var src = $('#searchresults').find(":selected").attr('data-src');

                var $newLi = $("<li><div1><img src='" + src + "'/></div1><div2><input type='text' id='college' name='college' value='" + task + "'/></div2><button class='up'>&#x2191</button><button class='down'>&#x2193</button></li>")
                    $newLi.attr("id", "newLi" + counter++);
            maxAppend++;
                    $("#tasks").append($newLi);
                });
```

I understand how to dynamically change the id of "li", however, the input within the $newLi variable is throwing me off. I tried setting the input to its own variable, but did not get too far.

In the end, i'd like to get the 'college' input name to become 'college1' upon button click, then 'college2' on the next click - - just like I have done with 'li' element.

Please let me know if I you need further clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use your counter variable in place of `id="college"`?

Comment: not sure i understand how to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your counter variable and insert it into the actual HTML markup the way you are the task variable

```
var $newLi = $("<li><div1><img src='" + src + "'/></div1><div2><input type='text' id='college" + counter + "' name='college" + counter + "' value='" + task + "'/></div2><button class='up'>&#x2191</button><button class='down'>&#x2193</button></li>")
```

Comment: beautiful. so simple!